# Problems set listener

Tags: backbone.js, model, view

im try config a listener to a model. I have a principal view (is a table) that contains the method render:

```
render: function(){
   sesiones.each(function(sesion){
      var view = new AuditoriaView({ aModel: sesion });
      this.$el.append(view.render());
   }, this);
   return this;
}
```

And have a secondary view, that represent a row (AuditoriaView):

```
initialize: function(aModel){
   this.model = aModel;
   // Cada vez que el modelo cambie, vuelve a renderizar
   this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
},
render: function(){
   this.$el.html("blablablablabla");
   return this;
}
```

This code, fails, with message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'

In the AuditoriaView line:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually passing the model but an Object. You can pass directly the model like this:

```
var view = new AuditoriaView(aModel);
```

or take the `aModel` from the parameter

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.model = options["aModel"];
    // Cada vez que el modelo cambie, vuelve a renderizar
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
},
```

EDIT:

or pass the model like this:

```
var view = new AuditoriaView({model: aModel});
```

Comment: It is not necessary to assign `this.model = options["aModel"];`. If you pass an object when you instantiate a Backbone.View`, `this.model` (if the object `{model:someModel}` is passed) is assigned prior to `initialize` being called. The same goes for a few other select attributes.